# nothing to repeat error using Scrapy when crawling geographic.org/streetview

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

My start URL is http://www.geographic.org/streetview/usa/index.html.

I am using the following code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin


class StreetViewSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "streetview"
    allowed_domains = ["geographic.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.geographic.org/streetview/usa/index.html"]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="*.html"), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('*.html',)), callback='parse_item')
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
        item = scrapy.Item()
        sub_urls = response.xpath("descendant-or-self::li/descendant-or-self::*/a/@href").extract()
        item['urls'] = map(lambda x: urljoin(response.url, x), sub_urls)
        return item
```

I only need the links and text of all `a` tags that have `*.html` in their URL and are with in the domain `www.geographic.org`. The crawler should go will the time we find `view.php` in `href` extracted.

I run the crawler using `scrapy crawl streetview` and I get:

```
> scrapy crawl streetview
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "E:\Miniconda2\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 148, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 243, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 330, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "F:\PyCharmProjects\streetview\streetview\spiders\collector.py", line 7, in <module>
    class StreetViewSpider(CrawlSpider):
  File "F:\PyCharmProjects\streetview\streetview\spiders\collector.py", line 13, in StreetViewSpider
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('*.html',)), callback='parse_item')
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\linkextractors\lxmlhtml.py", line 116, in __init__
    canonicalize=canonicalize, deny_extensions=deny_extensions)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\linkextractors\__init__.py", line 57, in __init__
    for x in arg_to_iter(allow)]
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are not supplying valid regular expression for `allow` attribute of `LinkExtractor` in the second rule. Also the `restrict_xpaths` attribute of `LinkExtractor` in the first rule won't work. Try going with these rules:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[contains(@href,'.html')]"), follow=True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.*\.html',)), callback='parse_item')
)
```